# Estimation of Temporal Correlation of Signal

Tags: estimation-theory, signal-analysis

I have a signal and i'd like to estimate its temporal correlation.

My limited understanding is i should compute the PSD by estimation using a parametric model such as AR.

However, i'm not quite clear on which mathematical techniques to use.

I'd be happy with any insignts or good sources of info (books)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The formula for the temporal corelation between a signal at time $k$ and the same signal at time $k+m$ is:
$$\rho_{k,k+m}=\frac{E((P_k-\overline P_k)(P_{k+m}-\overline P_{k+m}))}{\sqrt{ E((P_k-\overline P_k)^2 E((P_{k+m}-\overline P_{k+m})^2}}$$